# Is terminationgraceperiodseconds honored for the STS pod even if I delete the STS spec itself

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a use case where I need to add new volume mounts to the STS. In order to do that, I need to delete the old spec and add the new spec with volume.

What I am noticing is that when I delete the old STS spec, corresponding STS pods do not get terminationgraceperiodseconds (30 seconds). I can't find the proof of this behaviour in the documentation. Would terminationgraceperiodseconds will not be honored in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation under [Deleting the Statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/delete-stateful-set/)

> When deleting a StatefulSet through kubectl, the StatefulSet scales down to 0. All Pods that are part of this workload are also deleted. If you want to delete only the StatefulSet and not the Pods, use `--cascade=orphan`

You could also use an [updateStrategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#updating-statefulsets) for updating Statefulsets. There are two valid update strategies, `RollingUpdate` and `OnDelete`.

The strategy used is determined by the `spec.updateStrategy` field of the StatefulSet API Object. This feature can be used to upgrade the container images, resource requests and/or limits, labels, and annotations of the Pods in a StatefulSet.

Comment: But this doesn't seem to answer my question related to terminationgraceperiodseconds.. I am deleting sts and I am okay with the pod also getting deleted. But will k8 provide terminationgraceperiodseconds in this case or not?

Comment: If your app finishes shutting down and exits even before the terminationGracePeriod is done, it moves to the next step immediately and SIGKILL signal is sent to pod, and the pod is removed.

By default, all deletes are graceful within 30 seconds.